# Event on 'click' does not work on a link image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I try to migrate a VB6 application into a web based one. I stuck at some point where I am not able to troubleshoot it further. 
What I would like to do is to implement on click event on a class 'confirmation1' - link (black cross image).
I build the table rows in the following way:

```
var tr_str = "<tr>" +
"<td align='left'>" + result[i].produkt + "</td>" +
"<td align='right'>" + result[i].waga + "</td>" +
"<td align='right'>" + Math.round(result[i].kalorie) + "</td>" +
"<td align='right'>" + (Math.round(result[i].bialko * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
"<td align='right'>" + (Math.round(result[i].tluszcze * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
"<td align='right'>" + (Math.round(result[i].weglowodany * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + "</td>" +
"<td align='center'>" +
"<a href='test' title='Usuń' class='confirmation1'><img src='pictures/cross16.jpg' width='10' height='10' style='margin: 0px 0px' /></a>" ;
"</td>" +
"</tr>";
$("#TabelaDetali table").append(tr_str);
```

Then I do the following:

```
$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    console.log(product_name);
    });
```

I do not know why I cannot see this working. When I move a cursor over the cross image on the right side of the table (screenshot1 - table row 1st and 2nd, 7th column) or click it - nothing happens.
[image: screenshot1]

I know that there is a large part of a code hidden, but I do not know how to attache files here.
Any ideas how to troubleshoot it?

---

UPDATE1

I have copied code files here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/74bso1ux6noywhy/html.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have appended this html using jQuery, then you should use the `ON` event like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.confirmation1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    console.log(product_name);
});
```

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested, but it still does not work. No change at all.

Comment: I just tested the code with a dummy data and it seems to be working fine. Maybe you have other conflict in your logic, that do you see in the console?

Comment: I see nothing in web console. I do not see any product name. When I put console.log on the top of the e function I have also seen nothing.

Comment: how can I attach a files here? Can I copy a link to the files?

Comment: OK. I have solved the issue and found a workaround. The problem was css. I have added position: relative; into the table.TabelaSzara tbody td {} block. it works fine now with this settings.